# "...he heard Laucile say" (instead of says) can be correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the following text has a mistake or is it correct?

This book say "**say**" about 3rd person singular, apparently instead of "**says**", but I'm not sure if it is a typo or it's acceptable in such kind of literature (it is a professional book) or maybe I miss here a grammar rule.

This is a phrase from a book so called "*[Discovering Fiction Level 1 Student's Book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=rFHHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=One%20day%20he%20overheard%20her%20talking%20about%20him%20with%20a%20friend.%20Lucile%20was%20saying:%20%22other%20men%20live%20in&source=bl&ots=ZMqnsoQrKm&sig=J2FxcExa7XhkHwWccTtZiLPyMmY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGpu2xwZzaAhXiFJoKHQLwCk0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=One%20day%20he%20overheard%20her%20talking%20about%20him%20with%20a%20friend.%20Lucile%20was%20saying%3A%20%22other%20men%20live%20in&f=false)*":

> One day he overheard her talking about him with a friend. Lucile was
>   saying:
>
> "other men live in things and events and emotions and the future. but
>   he seems to know that living is something else..."
>
> What else? This friend interrupted curiously.
>
> and he heard Laucile **say**: "Well, of course every one knows, really. But he lives it too.".

[image]

Comment: It is correct, an example of reported speech. It was in the present when it was said.

Comment: He heard Lucile **say** instead of **says**?

Comment: I think I cannot explain what is happening here better than Anne W Zahra does in this [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-Let-it-go-wrong-Why-is-it-not-Let-it-goes). Please go check it out because I think it is the same topic about why "Let it go" is correct when I thought why not "Let it goes". Therefore, it is **correct**. All the credits go to Anne W Zahra and the website though.

Comment: It is correct.  It's a use of the bare infinite, because you conjugate the main verb ("he *heard*") but not a verb in the object phrase ("Laucile *say*")  I'm not sure of the exact grammar rule, or I would make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the special verbs like 'hear, see, watch'... and so on. I have seen many such examples where the main action is done by *someone else* who is observing, hearing, noticing or seeing. This is quite similar to the usage of 'let him *go*' and **not goes.** Because there too, the main action is *not* done by the third person.

> He heard Lucile say instead of says?

Because the main action *(of hearing)* is done by 'he.' We put 's' in a verb when the main action is done by the third person.

> He ***comes out*** of a car (main action of 'coming out' is performed by him). 
>  She **saw** him ***come out*** of a car (main action of 'seeing him' is performed by her).

Replacing the pronoun with a name makes no difference.

> Ricky ***comes out*** of a car 
>  Sonia saw Ricky ***come out*** of a car.

Comment: This is in principle similar to how we say *let him go*. That's a good example.